# Custom field always comes back as blank in Adaptive Payments

Tags: paypal

I am banging my heda against the wall with this adaptive PayPal stuff,

I have a payment going through successfully with PayPal using this data tied into a query string:
Array
(
    [actionType] => PAY
    [clientDetails.applicationId] => APP-80W284485P519543T
    [clientDetails.ipAddress] => 127.0.0.1
    [currencyCode] => GBP
    [memo] => Example
    [receiverList.receiver(0).amount] => 12.99
    [receiverList.receiver(0).email] => somebody@domain.com
    [receiverList.receiver(0).primary] => 1
    [requestEnvelope.errorLanguage] => en_UK
    [returnUrl] => http://mytest.com/checkout/order-received/466?key=wc_order_541b4a326eaad&utm_nooverride=1
    [cancelUrl] => http://mytest.com/cart/?cancel_order=true&order=wc_order_541b4a326eaad&order_id=466&redirect&_wpnonce=d1931afcbe
    [receiverList.receiver(1).amount] => 10.39
    [receiverList.receiver(1).email] => myemail@btinternet.com
    [receiverList.receiver(1).primary] => 
    [feesPayer] => SECONDARYONLY
    [invoice] => WC-466
    [custom] => My Custom Data here

)

The payment works, but the result I get in the IPN notification is this:
Array
(
    [transaction_subject] => 
    [txn_type] => web_accept
    [payment_date] => 14:10:36 Sep 18, 2014 PDT
    [last_name] => Glancy
    [residence_country] => GB
    [item_name] => 
    [payment_gross] => 
    [mc_currency] => GBP
    [business] => somebody@domain.com
    [payment_type] => instant
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [verify_sign] => Ai1PaghZh5FmBLCDCTQpwG8jB264A46g6S-.KIyxkgFbzDXDB6aGC1uL
    [payer_status] => verified
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_email] => payer@yahoo.co.uk
    [txn_id] => 7EY64200RX7806349
    [quantity] => 0
    [receiver_email] => somebody@domain.com
    [first_name] => Ben
    [payer_id] => YKFXVKBPJV4C6
    [receiver_id] => GAUFVLCQ8XYB8
    [memo] => Example
    [item_number] => 
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [mc_gross] => 12.99
    [custom] => 
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [ipn_track_id] => 74816a9b7d0f8
)
 GET:Array
(
    [wc-api] => WC_Gateway_Paypal_Adaptive
)

Now, I have no problems with receiving the VERIFIED when I post this stuff back to the url.

I have probably just spent too much time on this, but my question is why the does the IPN notification blank over my custom field when I get notified of the payment?

I should be getting the "My Custom data here" string back shouldn't I? Or is it different for Adaptive payments? I struggle a bit with the PayPal docs also

Comment: According to the PayPal documentation there is no such parameter "Custom" for the adaptive Payments . You can refer to the below url for all the available parameters . Might be you can use the some other parameter for the same purpose . https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/

Comment: You just made my day, I see, maybe I can use trackingID field. Really appreciate your reply, thankyou!